# ¿Cómo puedo reconocer desde Javascript si un input tiene la pseudoclase :valid?

Tags: javascript, html5, validación, input-type

¡Buenas!
Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma con Javascript para detectar si HTML5 le ha puesto como pseudoclase `:valid` o `:invalid`. Estoy intentando validar los elementos requeridos de un formulario pero también que estén bien rellenos.

PERO para eso necesito validar desde javascript algunas cosas antes de enviar el  formulario... Y para eso tengo que llamar a dicha función al darle al botón de enviar (porque  no sé hacerlo según se van rellenando).

Y, ya que el `input type="email"` ya se encarga de validar si se ha escrito un correo electrónico (o no es correcto), no necesito validarlo aposta con javascript. Para eso lo usaría con un `type="text"` normal y corriente.

Por eso me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de detectar si HTML5 le ha puesto a su campo `<input type="email">` la pseudoclase `:valid` o `:invalid`.

Porque si no, igualmente lo va a enviar aunque no tenga nada o no sea un email.

¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

intentaste ponerle un id o clase particular al campo?
Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="email" class="emailF" id="emailF">
```

Haciendo eso podrías acceder a ese elemento de manera fácil

```
iEmail = $("#emailF")

if(iEmail.hasClass("valid")){
//hacer algo
}else{
//hacer otra cosa
}
```

Comment: Sí, tiene su propio id. Lo que no  sé es cómo  se accede a esa propiedad hasClass... ¿está también en javascript normal? O sea, Javascript, no jQuery  o similares.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085567/what-is-the-hasclass-function-with-plain-javascript]

Ahi salen opciones a tu pregunta

Comment: Pero en el caso que  me mencionas es una clase dentro de un grupo de clases escritos en la etiqueta...  se esos  que van separados  por  espacios... Peroclaro, como supuestamente no es  una clase, sino una pseudoclase,  no me aclaro. Yestando en  inglés, más difícil  entenderlo.

Comment: He encontrando una forma de saber si tiene una clase con `document.getElementById("email_cliente").classList.contains("valid")` pero me de dado cuenta que no me detecta ni valid ni  invalid... Supongo que eso sólo es para clases, no para pseudoclases... O porque al no ser el botón submit, no llega a validarlo... Y si hago mediante botón submit y llamo a la función que hace las demás comprobaciones, ni me lo detecta, ni me deja enviar si el email es incorrecto. Pero de este modo, si todos los campos requeridos están rellenos, me lo envía, aunque las contraseñas no coincidan ¿Qué  puedo hacer?